# ApplicationLauncher.Callback notification on finishing Install4j installation

Tags: install4j

I am using autoupdate feature of install4J by using `ApplicationLauncher.launchApplicationInProcess()` API from my Java code.

This API has a parameter `ApplicationLauncher.Callback.` I thought this call-back method will be called when complete Installation process will finish.

But I observed that, this call back is not getting called when actual installation process (name of this process is same as setup file name) is completed.

Is there any callback mechanism to detect the status of installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate processes here:

- The updater, which is what you call with `ApplicationLauncher.launchApplicationInProcess()`
- The new installer, which is started downloaded and started by the updater.

The callback is called before the updater executes the installer, then the updater terminates itself. This sequence of events is required to avoid problems with locked or deleted files.

If you need to do something at the end of the installation, you have to place that logic in the installer.

Comment: As per your suggestion I have added Run Script action at the end of installation. This script checks return value of "context.isErrorOccurred()". Surprisingly it gives me "True" even though update is succeeded. Is there any other robust way to detect the installation status (fail/success/rollback) at the end of installation.

Comment: Success is a relative term that is defined by yourself. `context.isErrorOccurred()` returns `true` if any action has failed since the flag was last cleared. If the failure strategy of that action was "Continue" (which is the default), then the installer has not failed. If you arrive at the end of the installation, the installation was "successful". To react to rollback, register an event listener in the context.